# What is the best way to use inline CSS to position elements around a block specified by an external stylesheet?

Tags: css, layout, stylesheet, design-guidelines

How do I specify a position for the form generated part of this page and then use inline CSS to  place elements around it?
https://org2.democracyinaction.org/o/6351/p/salsa/event/common/public/?event_KEY=50926

Our half-baked temporary solution uses multiple Absolute elements. Unfortunately, these perform differently cross-browser and are especially bad on mobile (resulting in overflow and scrolling within the page elements).

Here is my addition to the external stylesheet, to move the form generated registration box up and to the left:

```
#regForm {width: 400px; position:absolute; clear:left; top:315px; }
```

Here are my inline attempts to arrange div elements around it:

```
<div> top element (quotes)
</div>
<div style="height:2400px"></div> 
//I put this in to keep the bottom page border from overlapping the absolute divs

<div style="position: absolute; top: 350px; left: 450px; width: 520px; 
overflow: auto; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;"> 
right column (of explanation text) </div>
<p></p>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 815px; left: 15px; width: 400px; 
overflow: auto; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">  
left column (more info about the #regForm box above, plus images) </div>
```

What we need to achieve:

```
[          top element         ]

[#regForm div] [right column   ]

[left column ]
```

Constraints:
we are reformatting a form generated page. I have one input panel where we can add HTML content to the page and use inline CSS. We also have access to add override elements to the external CSS stylesheet, but not to directly edit the whole stylesheet.

**tl:dr version:**  how do you use CSS to move an element (in this case #regForm) higher up in a page when you don't have access to edit the HTML that generates that element? Without styling, the #regForm element just gets appended to the end.

Comment: you can use !important tag before css to override elements

Comment: basically you want to change everything but the form?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the page to flow properly AND have #regdiv appear first, you could float the columns and the form, and then move the form up in the document tree with jQuery.

An example in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TjDmw/11/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="rightcol"></div>
<div id="leftcol"></div>
<div id="regdiv"></div><!--Last in HTML, but moved up with jQuery-->
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    border:2px black solid;
    width:400px;    
    float:left;
}
#rightcol{
    background:red;
    width:200px;
    height:400px;
    float:right;
}
#leftcol{
    background:blue;
    width:160px;
    height:450px;
    float:left;
}
#regdiv{
    background:green;
    width:140px;
    height:220px;
    float:left;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#regdiv').insertBefore('#rightcol');​
```

​

Comment: Yes, thank you! There's also a top row, so I gather that could be added like so: 
http://jsfiddle.net/TjDmw/15/